# Custom View and Layout Animation android

Tags: android

I have a layout which at start has '0dp' width but when a button is clicked it animates from Left to right and its width is increased accordingly. In this layout I am initializing a custom view. The view is initialized correctly when I place it at right or at centre but when I place it on the left it's not shown.

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">
    <com.example.Wheel
        android:id="@+id/wheel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    </com.example.Wheel>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is what I do in java:

```
MenuListLeft = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ControlLayout);
openButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isExpandedLeft) {
            isExpandedLeft = false;
            MenuListLeft.startAnimation(new CollapseAnimationLTR(MenuListLeft, 0,(int)(screenWidth*1), 5));
        }
        else {
            isExpandedLeft = true;
            MenuListLeft.startAnimation(new ExpandAnimationLTR(MenuListLeft, 0,(int)(screenWidth*1), 5));
            init();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better of using weights in a combination of Relative and Linear Layout rather than just in a Relative Layout.
Here...
weight = 0 gets you no space expansion. Try setting it to 1.
In case you want to understand more on how weight works:
http://teamdroid.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/android-layout-weight-explained/

Also, for your case, wouldn't a View.Visibility GONE, VISIBLE...with animation may work better.